# How to find which region is your game client?

Tags: diablo-iii

[This thread](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4210107113?page=1) suggests that an update loop when playing on EU servers could be caused by having a US game client version instead of EU.

Is there a way to check which client version you have installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `agent.db` file under `Battle.net\Agent` folder with Notepad++ or similar programs (if you have Windows 7 the full path is `c:\ProgramData\Battle.net\Agent\agent.db`, I don't have Windows XP to get the full path).

Search for string `"patch_url" and look at the patch server address:

- If url starts with enGB the client is the EU English version
- If url starts with enSG the client is the Singapore English version
- If url starts with enUS the client is the American English version

Comment: Hmm ... and if I changed it to EU, will it make my Patch Hell problems go away? The problems right now is that new patches are rolled to US before EU, so my client updates, and then is too advanced for the EU servers.

Comment: I had the same problem, I tried to modify agent.db in order to redirect to enGB patch servers but I failed. The best way is to download the enGB setup from Battle.net, launch it and follow the procedure describe [here](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4525922749) to reduce at minimum the size of the download. I just did it and I need to download only 1.05 GB or so.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options -> Accounts and check out your language setting. In the EU version "English (British)" should appear.